# Is there any non-Windows way to run a shell command from a local .html file?

Tags: javascript, macos, shell

- I have a Mac.
- I have an html file.
- I have a javascript equipped browser.
- And whatever else I might need.

How do I run a bash command from the html file?

"Whatever else I might need" can include Java.  TiddlyWiki uses a Java applet to save a file to my harddrive.  This is close to what I want, I just don't know how to set that up.

Please ignore whether or not this is advisable for now.

Comment: I'm curious what it means to _run a `bash` command from the html file_ -- HTML doesn't _do_ anything, it isn't a programming language. Maybe you could figure out some way to get JavaScript to call `system(3)` on an arbitrary string, and if you find a way, please report it as a bug :) browsers aren't supposed to be doing that.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to do, but if all you want to do is run a command from the web, you could use `curl` to hit the web page (potentially in html) and then parse it with sed/awk/grep to find the command you want to run, then execute it.  If you really need the browser simply visiting a page to run a command on the browsers machine, you won't be able to do this.  It violates all the sandbox security stuff they've set up and would be a massive security hole if it were possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simply not possible to do using only your Mac, an html file, and a Javascript-capable browser.

Essentially, you would need to develop your own browser plugin if you ever want this to be possible; alternatively maybe someone has already created such a plugin to grossly violate standard security boundaries.

Have you considered an alternative solution?  Why are you bound to a browser?

Comment: I intend to use TiddlyWiki to manage my notes for my programming projects.  When TiddlyWiki is opened, it runs several javascript configuration scripts.  TiddlyWiki makes it easy to add more strait from the browser w/o digging into the html source.  It would be nice to open up my TiddlyWiki notes and have my entire programming environment come up at the same time in the background.

Comment: If you're hosting the wiki locally, you could write a back-end script (in, say, PHP) which performs the desired invocations.  Then you simply have your JS code query that PHP script by any number of possible means - XHR, use the script as a link source, *etc.*  The only additional caveat then is that your web server will need to have the appropriate permissions to launch the applications you require, and those applications will by default run as the invoking user (*i.e.*, the uid of the server process that launched your script).

Comment: I would also add that you may want to update your original question to more accurately reflect your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this - it's a security thing. The browser will never run anything from a website on a shell level.

Answer (score 0):

Windows used to have Jscript and Wscript, which, although they were not actually run *in* the browser, they could update html views and run as proper applications.

What is your goal here? If your goal is to program a UI for a local application as a website, there are certainly ways to do that. If your goal is to bring abilities of local applications to a web applications, there are ways to do that as well. However, if it is the latter, then it is most likely that you should rethink your goals.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of doing this is to use the [WScript.Shell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aew9yb99%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object (only available on Windows and even then it probably won't without some pretty unusual security settings on the client PC), or using an ActiveX control.

I don't know if an ActiveX control will even work on a Mac, or if you can do the same things with an ActiveX control as you can on a Windows PC, but it might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how this is done on a mac, but here is my windows solution. You need to create your own protocol (aka myproto:// instead of http://) then in the registry at the listening end you have a program -- using a scripting language like AutoIt is good here. You will recieve a URL, that url has to be UNescaped to reveal whatever message you are sending to your ad-hoc program, then let your program do whatever suits. The message could be a direct command line string (not recommended :P) or what have you. On the browserside you just make urls like myproto://<escaped command> so they are no fun to write by hand haha.